# 6.6kV digital isolator pad clearance

Tags: isolation, clearance

I was wondering about digital isolators. I have some temperature sensors installed inside the windings of a 6.6kV motor. I would like for my system to not be completely destroyed in case of a short.

For instance, the Si86xxT isolators from Silicon Labs. They offer 5kVrms isolation for up to 1 second.

But how about clearance between the uncoated pads/leads? According to [this](https://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html) calculator I have seen used in other answers, about 33mm of clearance between the pins is needed. But the wide body package of the Si86xxT devices do not even offer half that (~7.5mm).

How do you protect your device for longer than 1 second? I had thought about fuses on both input lines but this does not sound ideal, you can't be sure the fuses would blow fast enough.

How can they claim such a high isolation voltage if the clearance is not large enough?

Comment: those calculators work against IPC-2221 which considers "working voltage", that voltage for a prolonged period.

Comment: If you're worried about fuses not blowing, you might want to investigate a crowbar circuit.  This is a bit above my head so there are probably better solutions, but a crowbar circuit shorts two lines when exposed to overvoltage (or a control signal), causing a massive amount of current to flow and ensuring fuses blow.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to add additional thermally conductive isolation to the sensor?

Comment: if you expect longer transients you need external protection. Most commonly at these voltage spark gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UL60950 norm.

There's a table that answers your question.

Clearance depends also on the pollution class of the environment where your board will work in.

There are 3 classes, where 3 is the most polluted environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the application note attached to the isolator?
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN583.pdf

There are lots of factors to consider here, such as pollution, conformal coating, etc.

It's also worth noting that you are intending to use a 5kV isolator with 6,6kV potential. Even with sufficient external clearance the internals of the chip could break down.

As other mention the IPC-2221 clearance is defined to safely operate on the listed voltages. For *transient* events you require much shorter clearances but as I understand you can short out to a 6.6kV system *permanently*. If that is the case, then you should follow the IPC clearances.

Electric arcs is highly dependent on surface contaminants, so you still need quite a bit of margin between your design and test voltage, as illustrated by table 2.3 in the application note. If you were to design a circuit to survive a 6.6kV situation it must be tested to a much higher voltage. Your test voltage is going to be in the 10's of kV's.

I am absolutely convinced that your employer, or the owner of the motor, has a specification of the required standards to follow here. A 5kV isolator in a 6.6kV system seems incorrect and unsafe. There are laws and standards you should follow here. The linked application note shows several of the terms you should be familiar with.

(And quite honestly I am shocked that you write that you *have* a temperature sensor installed, but seek advice on safety now. That sensor seems incredibly dangerous, please be careful. )

Comment: Thanks Arcatus, for your concern. The sensors are installed by our motor manufacturers inside the winding. My employer wants to create their own sensing circuit for these sensors so that is the reason they are already installed. I won't be testing with the high voltage motors for quite some time. Safety is always my number 1 priority.